axios - I can't intercept the response
I'm trying to debug why my request isn't sent or is has wrong data, but I'm not able to check the response. I tried 'axios-debug-log' and it shows that request is sent, but no data about response code. I've also tried to intercept the request which look all right, but I'm not able to see the response data or response status.
    axios.interceptors.request.use((request: any) => {
        console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2))
        return request
    })

    axios.interceptors.response.use((response: any) => {
        console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
        return response
    })

    axios.post(
        'https://api.zephyrscale.smartbear.com/v2/testexecutions/', data,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    ).then((response: any) => {
        return response
    })

I've tried different intercepting codes and none of them worked.
I just want to know why the request doesn't hit the server or which data in the request is wrong.

Is the code running in browser or server-side?

@Mikkel the code is triggered by webdriver io in the 'onTestPass' hook

Interesting. I f I run a JS file with Node.js with your code snippet (removing undefined variables like data and headers) then I get a 401 Unauthorized response.

Right, that's valuable input. I was focusing on a wrong code, but finally I implemented this feature completely different. Test report is a simple json, and I've created separate script that sends results to the testcase manager on demand.
